# Type assert an element in a JS file with @ts-check

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc, ts-check

I have a JS file with a `// @ts-check` directive, using JSDoc comments to denote types.

The problem is that the elements fail type checks when retrieved from the `document`.

So we have in HTML:

```
<input id="myInput">...
```

When I get this element in JS the type checking throws an error:

```
// @ts-check
const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
myInput.value = 'foobar';
```

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

If I specify the expected type with a JSDoc `@type` comment then that also fires an error:

```
// @ts-check

/** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
myInput.value = 'foobar';
```

> Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.
> Property 'accept' is missing in type 'HTMLElement'.

If I was in TS, I could use `document.getElementById('myInput') as HTMLInputElement` to tell it that I expect this type.

How do I do this in JS with `@ts-check`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The fix for this is to put the `@type` declaration between the variable and the retrieval, and adding `()`.

Like this:

```
// @ts-check

const myInput = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (document.getElementById('myInput'));
myInput.value = 'foobar';
```

This syntax is fairly clunky and horrible, but they've [closed the bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17453#issuecomment-325779732) so I guess the above syntax is the *official* way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a runtime check if you want to be absolutely sure, this also persuades typescript that the assignment is safe.

```
const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
if (myInput instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
    myInput.value = 'foobar';
}
```

Comment: Cheers, but in this context I specifically don't want a runtime check, as in the basically impossible case where `myInput` is not an `HTMLInputElement` I've got nothing to do instead except throw an exception. Belt and braces is fine, but I have loads of elements, which means loads of belts and loads of braces, which just feels like a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Keith is excellent, but it only covers individual **Element** nodes via:

- `@type {HTMLInputElement}`

We also need to deal with **HTMLCollections** - which we can do via:

- `@type {HTMLCollectionOf<Element>}`

Faced with a long file of javascript which may contain any number of **Element** and **HTMLCollection** captures, we can take advantage of the following two search and replace Regexes:

**Find Element captures:**

```
((let|const|var)\s([^\s=]+)\s?=)\s?(([^\.]+)\.(((get|query)[^\(]+\(([^\)]+\))\[\d+\])|(getElementById|querySelector)\(([^\)]+\))))
```

**Replace with:**

```
$1 /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ ($4)
```

Then...

**Find HTMLCollection captures:**

```
((let|const|var)\s([^\s=]+)\s?=)\s?(document\.(get|query)[^\(]+\(([^\)]+\)))
```

**Replace with:**

```
$1 /** @type {HTMLCollectionOf<Element>} */ ($4)
```